# avoiding destroy with foreign key

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails-4, foreign-keys

I'm new in Ruby on Rails. I don't understand how rails behave using foreign Key, I've researched it for some days but I didn't get the answer.

Simple sample:

I created two tables:

```
class CreatePosts < ActiveRecord::Migration
 def change
  create_table :posts do |t|
   t.string :title
   t.text :content
   t.timestamps null: false
  end
 end
end


class CreateComments < ActiveRecord::Migration
 def change
  create_table :comments do |t|
   t.string :author
   t.text :content
   t.references :post, index: true, foreign_key: true
   t.timestamps null: false
  end
 end
end
```

My models are:

```
class Post < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :comments
end

class Comments < ActiveRecord::Base
 belongs_to :post
end
```

My doubt is: As I have a Foreign Key in my table COMMENTS (.references :post, index: true, foreign_key: true) I guess that I wouldn't be able to destroy any post which has any COMMENTS associated to them, isn't it ?

I did as above but I am still able to destroy the posts, even when I have the comments associated. How can I treat it? What am I doing wrong?

Cheers

Comment: Also, I am using SQL LITE, when i check my .schema the FK doesn;t seems to be created:

Comment: sqlite> .schema posts
   CREATE TABLE "posts" ("id" INTEGER PRIMARY KEY            AUTOINCREMENT NOT NULL, "title" varchar, "content" text,  "created_at" datetime NOT NULL, "updated_at" datetime NOT NULL);

Comment: CREATE TABLE "comments" ("id" INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT NOT NULL, "author" varchar, "content" text, "post_id" integer, "created_at" datetime NOT NULL, "updated_at" datetime NOT NULL);
CREATE INDEX "index_comments_on_post_id" ON "comments" ("post_id");

Comment: As per given your example It should work. Might be you are some thing missing.

Answer (score 2):

I'd refine your migrations to use the `:on_delete` options on your foreign keys. It can take one of those values : `:nullify, :cascade, :restrict`

From what I understand, you need to set this value to `:restrict` on your `post_id` column in your `comments` table, so that posts with associated comments can't be deleted.

Update:
Or, you could also directly set it on the association in your `Post` model:

```
has_many :comment, dependent: :restrict_With_error
```

Please take a look at:
http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/ConnectionAdapters/SchemaStatements.html#method-i-add_foreign_key
http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/Associations/ClassMethods.html#method-i-has_many  -> See the Options: Section

Answer (score 0):

From what i understand, you dont want to destroy a `post` if there are associated `comments`?

Why not put a `if statement` encapsulating the delete button for a `post`

So something like:

*psudo code*

```
 if @post.comments exists
    cant delete post
 else
    delete post
 end
```